# How to store an rsync backup of my system on a NFS mount?

Tags: permissions, rsync, backup, nfs

I'd like to use `rsync` to make a backup of my complete system including files owned by `root` and myself  as well as other system and non-system users. I'd like to be able to restore the source directory structure and files from the backup target with `rsync` including ownership and permissions.

After experiencing trouble with pathes longer then 260 characters on `cifs` (yes, this is ridiculous), I'm trying out NFS 4.1 which seems to have a difficult to control mapping of user and group ids. My understanding is that `root_squash`, `no_root_squash` and `all_squash` all to control the mapping to the user `anonymous`. However, specifying `no_root_squash` in `/etc/exports` still causes the mounted directory to be owned by `nobody:nobody` on the client side. The same applies to all files transferred on the mount with `rsync -a` (`rsync` transfers the files, but each change of the ownership to `root` fails due to `chown "[path] failed: Invalid argument (22)`).

I'm using other forms of versioning backups as well, so there's no need to discuss the suitability of `rsync` for backups. Creating an image on the NFS or CIFS mount and giving it a filesystem is a solution (resulting in one very large and thus hard to manage file) as is creating `tar`s which are hard to update on a daily basis. I'm looking for a solution for the specific use case.

Comment: This QA on ServerFault might be helpful: https://serverfault.com/q/213647/349846

Comment: Using any sort of network file system is going to be slow, using a rsync server or over ssh is 2nd best to a btrfs Incremental Backup.

Comment: I'd recommend decoupling `rsync` from your NFS questions.  Properly set up, root on a client can create/chown a file on the server to any other user.  If this isn't happening, you need to solve that first.  v3 or v4?

Comment: @Haxiel The answer to the question is to drop ownership of the files which is a bad idea for a backup.

Comment: @user1133275 Target is a Synology box which handles all network filesystem and file protocol transfer very close to maximum speed.

Comment: @Karl The two other answers on that QA also discuss a problem with the target UID/GIDs not existing on the server, causing the chown command to fail.

Comment: You won't get block incremental with rsync over NFS. You would be better enabling ssh to the Synology and doing rsync to that as a remote server, ignoring NFS completely for the backup.

Answer (score 0):

Working with the Synology limitation your options are to not backup ownership, or use --fake-super, or use duplicity etc.

Getting a Linix server (optional lxc/kvm security) you can backup ownership, and reduce bandwidth by using a server side rsync for your client rsync to talk to.

Or remove diff cpu and IO time completely with btrfs Incremental Backup (auto rename tracking to).